# Creating a selector with variable of function type

Tags: swift, selector

I am working on two views that are subclassing subclass of UITableViewCell. In the base one (subclass of UITableViewCell) I am trying to setup gesture recognizer in a way that each of super class could change the behavior (eventually call didTapped method on it's delegate) of the tap.

I have written following code. I can use `#selector(tap)`, however I think that using a variable instead of overriding a tap method in each super class is a much cleaner way. Is it even possible to use something like `#selector(tapFunc)`? If no what would be the cleanest and best from engineering point of view solution?

```
class BaseCell: UITableViewCell {

    @objc var tapFunc: () -> () = { () in
        print("Tapped")
    }

    @objc func tap() {
        print("TEST")
    }

    func setupBasicViews(withContent: () -> ()) {

        let tapGestureRecoginzer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapFunc))
        contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        contentView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecoginzer)
    }
}
```

And then two views that are building on top of this one:

```
class ViewA: BaseCell {

    //don't want to do this
    override func tap() {
        //do stuff
    }

    func setup {
        //setup everything else
    }

class ViewB: BaseCell {

   var delegate: ViewBProtocool?

    func setup {
        tapFunc = { () in
            delegate?.didTapped(self)
        }
        //setup everything else
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not too far off. Make the following changes:

```
class BaseCell: UITableViewCell {
    var tapFunc: (() -> Void)? = nil

    // Called by tap gesture
    @objc func tap() {
        tapFunc?()
    }

    func setupBasicViews(withContent: () -> ()) {

        let tapGestureRecoginzer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
        contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        contentView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecoginzer)
    }
}

class ViewA: BaseCell {
    func setup() {
        //setup everything else
    }
}

class ViewB: BaseCell {
    var delegate: ViewBProtocol?

    func setup() {
        tapFunc = {
            delegate?.didTapped(self)
        }
        //setup everything else
    }
}
```

Now each subclass can optionally provide a closure for the `tapFunc` property.

I show above that `tapFunc` is optional with no default functionality in the base class. Feel free to change that to provide some default functionality if desired.

Comment: i was going to suggest using a variable of the `Selector` type, but I like your solution of a fixed selector that invokes a closure much better. (Voted)